# Bluetooth and internet connection in background (android)

Tags: android, service, background, bluetooth, wifi

I want to develop an application that use the internet connection and the bluetooth connection in background. Each 5min my application get information from my bluetooth device and send the data on a server via the internet connection. It's possible to have internet and bluetooth connection in background on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this would be possible, You would want to use some form of service or ASyncTask to handle this which could sleep for five minutes to avoid any excess battery drain. You will also need to ensure that the app does not close when the user leaves the app so that you can continue sending and receiving data.

Here's some help on the internet side of things:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

and bluetooth:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html

That should be enough for you to get started, best of luck! :)